# REGEX match everything except first zero

Tags: regex, google-sheets

My regex skills are very low. I can fake my way through some things, but have no real knowledge. I have phone numbers formatted as +610412123123, which is semi-valid, but I need it as +61412123123. ie. remove the first zero. I can't just do something that only captures [1-9] because +610412100023 needs to come out as +61412100023.

I'm working in Google Sheets using =REGEXEXTRACT().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `REGEX`

Shorter and simpler:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A2,0,"",1)
```

`REGEX` version will be:

```
 =REGEXREPLACE(to_text(A2),"(.*?)0(.*)","$1$2")
```

Comment: Although unnecessary,  `REGEXEXTRACT` version to match everything except the first zero will be `=CONCATENATE(REGEXEXTRACT(to_text(A2),"(.*?)0(.*)"))`

Comment: I have to mark this as best answer. I've used Substitute before, but never like this. That's great!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`REGEXREPLACE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en), not `REGEXEXTRACT()`. Use a capture group to capture the part before the first `0` and copy it to the replacement.

```
=REGEXREPLACE('cellname', "^([^0]*)0", "$1")
```